# Virtualhost X works but 404s on anything in the folder

Tags: localhost, virtualhost

Ok, I've just set up my virtualhost x so that

site.dev is pointed at a folder on my Mac.

when apache is on going to site.dev works and gives a "It Works!" in the browser.

if I then go to anything I know is in the local folder, like index.php or robots.txt I get thrown a 404.

I'm missing something vitally key in this set up I think, any ideas?

I've also checked that web sharing is on and I've PHP is enabled on the machine also. Stil no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is because permissions aren't set to allow it to work, try setting the permissions on a file to 777 initially and work back from there to make them more secure; not that it really matters locally but always good practice :-)